# docker-compose is starting containers after host reboot. Which ones?

Tags: docker, path, docker-compose, reboot, autostart

I'm new to `docker-compose`. Before, when I started containers manually, after a host reboot I had to start the containers manually.

Today I found that -after a host reboot- I had 4 containers running. Those were previously started with `docker-compose`.

But `docker-compose` does not work well unless you are in the proper directory with the `docker-compose.yml`.

## Question

How can I know what `docker-compose.yml` or (which path) was used to launch the docker containers that I find already started as soon as I login after a reboot?

I tried

```
docker inspect xxxxx
```

but I could not find any clue on what `docker-compose.yml` was used to launch.

Comment: Have you set [restart](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#restart) in compose file or use `docker inspect $container` to see if any restart was set for these auto up containers?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`docker-compose` is not starting anything.

The Docker daemon is starting containers on which you have set a restart policy (possibly in one of your `docker-compose.yaml` files). You can simply remove these containers (`docker container rm ...`) if you don't need them anymore, or you can reset the restart policy using `docker container update --restart=no <image_name_or_id>`.

You can read more about restart policies [here](https://docs.docker.com/config/containers/start-containers-automatically/).

> But docker-compose does not work well unless you are in the proper directory with the docker-compose.yml.

Since docker-compose isn't involve at this stage (it may have been responsible for *creating* the containers but it is not responsible for restarting them), this isn't a problem. Setting an appropriate restart policy on your containers via your `docker-compose.yml` is the correct way to enable containers to start at boot.

---

You can set a restart policy when you start a container using `docker run` by including the appropriate `--restart=<policy>` option on the command line.

Comment: Ahh I see, just to confirm: I could also manually start a container with `docker`, nothing to do with `docker-compose` and set a "restart policy" that will ensure the container is launched again upon reboot. Nothing to do with the `compose`, but with the `dockerd` itself. Is that true?

Comment: Correct. You can set a restart policy when you start a container using `docker run --restart=<policy> ...`.

Comment: Ah, seen and tested!! I'm gonna accept the answer as "the answer", and to improve it I'd suggest you edit it to include your last comment in the answer itself.

Answer (score 1):

*in compose file use restart: always* to run after machine is rebooted

```
 services:   
   service1:
    image: serice1:latest
    restart: always
```